# Prove if $f'$ is a Riemann-integrable function then $f(x)= a_{0} +cx + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } a_{n} \cos(nx)+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } b_{n} \sin(nx)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am trying to prove the following, but I ran into problems:

Suppose that $f:[-\pi, \pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $f':[-\pi, \pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is Riemann-integrable. Show that there exists $c, a_{0}, a_{1}, a_{2},.... b_{1}, b_{2} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } |a_{n}| $ and $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } |b_{n}|$

converge, and

$f(x)= a_{0} +cx + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } a_{n} \cos(nx)+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } b_{n} \sin(nx)$

for all $ x \in [-\pi, \pi] $

where should I start?

Can I start by stating if is  if $f'$ is Riemann integrable then
$f'(x)= d_{0} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } d_{n} \cos(nx)+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } e_{n} \sin(nx)$?

Comment: It is not generally true that if $f'(x)$ is Riemann integrable that $f'(x)$ is equal to its fourier series. Since each of the terms $\cos(nx)$ and $\sin(nx)$ are periodic, their sum is periodic, so we must have $f'(\pi)=f'(-\pi)$ in order to hope that the series will converge to the function itself. You can make a weaker statement about convergence almost everywhere though.

Comment: Good point, thank you. I was thinking I would start with that because it seems that if I integrate f' over [-pi, x] then I get the linear term cx. But now my approach does not work anymore.

Comment: If you assume that $f'(x)$ converges uniformly its Fourier series, then you can integrate term by term to get a sequence guaranteed to converge to $f$.

Comment: If $f' \in L^1([-\pi,\pi])$, then even if the Fourier series for $f'$ is not convergent, it can be formally integrated termwise to obtain a convergent Fourier series for $f(x) = \int_0^x f'(t) \, dt$.  Note that as an integral $f$ must be continuous and of bounded variation and so its Fourier series is convergent.

Comment: ... and the Fourier series for $f$ will exactly match the series obtained by formally integrating the series for $f'$ termwise.  See this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1825080/148510) for a sine series -- and which generalizes to a full series.

Answer (score 1):

If $f^{'}$ is Riemann-integrable it is bounded so it is in $L^{2}$.
It means that its Fourier coefficients are in $l_{2}$.
At the same time if $a_{n}(f)$ is a Fourier coefficient $f$ and $a_{n}(f^{'})$ is a Fourier coefficient $f^{'}$ then $$|a_{n}(f^{'})| = n*|a_{n}(f)|$$. The rest is just Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, that is:
$$\sum |a_n| = \sum n* |a_{n}(f)| *(\frac{1}{n}) = \sum |a_{n}(f^{'})| *(\frac{1}{n}) <=
\sqrt(\sum |a_{n}(f^{'})|^{2}) * \sqrt(\sum (\frac{1}{n})^{2})$$

Comment: for clarity  the star (∗) you have in your formula is the product - correct?

Comment: yes, standard product between numbers

Comment: while the above is sufficient to demonstrate convergence of the coefficients, it is enough to prove that the function $f$ can be written as  $f(x)= a_{0} +cx + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } a_{n} \cos(nx)+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } b_{n} \sin(nx) ?$ The part that I struggle is that not every function can be written as sum of Fourier coefficients expecially when the function is not assumed to be periodic.

Comment: Yes because since the series of coefficients is absolutely convergent the Fourier series with these coefficients is uniformly convergent.  In words, representation as in your comment above makes sense since the right hand side is finite (convergent).

Comment: clearly starting from $f'(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } c_{n} \cos(nx)+ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } d_{n} \sin(nx)$ and integrating from $-\pi $ to $x$

Comment: No, you do not know if $f^{'}$ has convergent Fourier series ... we only proved that $f$ enjoys this property.